# Rebol Cannot close view window on Mac OS X and I cannot enter anything in field

Tags: rebol

I cannot close window on Mac OS X 10.6.4 and I cannot enter anything in field. REBOL/View 2.7.7.2.5 5-Jan-2010

Update: this occurs when I escape the console program I executed here http://askcodegeneration.com/rebol-form/

```
  window: layout [
      H1 "Demo"
      style rightlabel label right 120x24
      across
      rightlabel "First Name" First-Name: field "Enter First Name" Return rightlabel "Last Name" Last-Name: field "Enter Last Name" Return rightlabel "Age" Age: field "Enter Age" Return rightlabel "Note" Note: Area "Enter Note" Return
     rightlabel
      space 0
      button "Submit" [
          ;close the window for the program to continue
          unview
      ]
      button "Cancel" [unview]
  ]

View Window
```

Answer (score 3):

anytime you escape in the console, the event management stops.

just do   do-events   to start up even handling again.

closing the console window should always closes all view windows.

Comment: I don't think it behaves like this on Windows will check again and come back.